# Do i need a slice for each instance of state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

So I'm trying to understand redux toolkit slices and reducers. An example from the API is as follows:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

    const counterSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'counter',
        initialState: 0,
        reducers: {
            increment: (state) => state + 1,
    },
})
```

So every slice has an initial state. Does that mean if i have a component with 14 different use/set states, that I have to make 14 slices? (as an example) or can I have multiple different 'initialStates"? I don't see how a reducer would handle that, as if I had 14 different reducers, I would need initialState values for each wouldn't I?

This question has come up as im trying to convert a single functional component that uses useState/setState/useEffect and I'm not really sure based on the docs how to go about doing that.

An example from my codebase:

```
    const NewProjectModal = ({ onClose, scrap }) => {
        const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
        const [submitButtonDisabled, setSubmitButtonDisabled] = 
        useState();
        const { user = {} } = useAuthToken();
```

So with redux toolkit, i would need 3 slices to handle this, as a slice can only have 1 initial state? or would i use an array of objects, and call that my initial state, and then just modify each object with an action?
const [backgroundPage, setBackgroundPage] = useState();

Comment: States are just logical groupings of....um....state. There's no hard right or wrong answer. A functional component with 4 `useStates` could, potentially in theory, work just fine as if it had just one `useState` that was an object instead of a primitive. Don't worry about the **right** way. Build it until it feels uncomfortable.

Comment: Also, a single component in my opinion, but almost objectively, should not have 14 different `useStates` - that component is doing too many things at that point. Components should be simple. If you think they can't be simple, look how simple your `App` component is.

Comment: Thank you adam. I think i know what you are saying and updated the question.

Comment: The idea of a `redux slice` may not be to necessarily replace each & every single state (ie, `useState`) variable in a component. `redux` has a fundamental objective: to help share state across components. May be one uses the `slice` only to store those state variables which will be needed outside a given component? May be one sets `initialState: {dataOne: false, dataTwo: '', dataThree: [], dataFour: {}}` where `data` 1, 2, 3, 4 are all individual `state` variables within a component?